# Java - Creating a class to dynamically determine if user has access to the calling method

Tags: java

I have tried doing a search for this but I fear I may not be wording what I want to do very well.

Currently, we have about a hundred action classes in our application with each determining if a user has access to it. I would like to make a class that can figure out the calling method, what permissions are required for it, and if the user has those permissions. Unfortunately, I don't really know how to even get started with this as each class may have slightly different requirements.

I'm happy to add more explanation if needed but as I said, I'm not sure I'm wording what I'm trying to do very well so if anyone has a better way of putting it that gets me some google results or a link to a related question here that's already been answered, I know I'd appreciate it.

current permissions checks look like below. This is a simple implementation, there are usually multiple profile checks in one if block.

`If (scc.getUser().getCurrentProfile().getSystemAdmin() != 1) {
logIllegalAccess(log);
break;
}`

Comment: How are the permissions configured? Please post some code fragments if you can

Comment: Well, if you *don't know the logic* for determining whether or not a user is authorized to perform an operation, then there's no way for you to implement that logic.  Creating a class with methods which perform logic is the easy part, but you have to be able to actually define that logic.  First you have to determine how a user is authorized for an action, then you can implement the code to determine that.

Comment: @vikingsteve Edited to show a basic example

Comment: @David2 The logic being used to determine if a user has access is simple, they do an if check and if they have one of the profiles required then they are kicked back to the home page.

Comment: This is not really an answerable question, as it is very fuzzy and you admit yourself that your wording is unsure. I can guess that you should formulate all possible things to be checked, associate them with operations for checking them, then create a mapping from operations (methods?) to lists of operations and parameters to check.

Comment: @RealSkeptic would it be best to create a class that has all the action class names and the roles a member needs detailed and then have another class that references that list to determine if a user has appropriate rights? sorry for the fuzzy questions, I've still got a lot to learn.

Comment: Real application security is a complex topic and I'd advise against "rolling your own" because 1) there are many ways to get it wrong, and 2) doing so could squarely land in the category of "reinventing the wheel."  Perhaps you should consider the security frameworks (freely available or commercial) already available to Java SE and adapt those to your use case.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the most elegant solution would make use of annotation processing. The idea is that you would annotate action classes with a custom annotation, something like:

```
@RequiredPermission(Permissions.SYSADM)
class ActionA {
  public ActionA newInstance() {
    return new ActionA_Gen(new ActionA());
  }
  private ActionA() {...}
  ...
}
```

Action classes would have to have a `newInstance()` method to be used to create instances instead of calling `new`. The method would create an instance of a class by the same name with `_Gen` extension. This class would have one method for each method in the original action class, which would perform a permission check and call the corresponding method in the original class instance that was passed to its constructor. 
The `_Gen` class would be generated by an annotation processor.

Note that by using reflection it might be possible to move the `newInstance()` method in a common superclass.

Comment: An elegant solution indeed .... if his application was already running within the context of a framework that provided the security processing.

Comment: Thank you for the information I'll be looking more into the method you've suggested. For scott, the application is built with spring and reflection. I still have a lot to learn about frameworks as they seem like mystical beasts to me right now, but do they provide the security processing you're speaking of?

This is all for a story I want to get written for an upcoming sprint which I know is backwards, the PO's should be dealing with it, but they're incompetent at best and I'm still new to java.